# json4s used in scalatra application throws "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input"

Tags: scala, json4s, scalatra

json4s used in scalatra application throws "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input" when a POST request through a browser.

I have a ScalatraServlet to serve FORM submit from browser. Here is the Servlet.

```scala
class PagesController(service: RecordService) extends ScalatraServlet with JacksonJsonSupport  {

  post("/addRecord") {
    contentType = "text/html"
    //implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val jsonPayload = request.body
    println(s"payload: $jsonPayload")
    val x = parse(request.body)
    println(s"parsed: $x")
    val record = x.extract[MRecord]
    println(s"object: $record")
    service.add(Record(0, "Mocked data"))
    println(s"added $recordModel")
    redirect(URL.LANDING_PAGE_URL)
  }
```

When I run the POST request through cli/rest-client with content-type as *appplication/www-form-url-encode*, there is no such error and I can confirm from the *println* statements. However, when a browser submits a form, "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input"

What is the cause of this exception to occur only when the form is submitted and not when submitted through REST client/cli?

Comment: Which version of scalatra and json4s are you using?

Comment: ```Scalatra version : 2.7.0``` and ```json4 is 3.5.5```

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code expects that a request body is JSON but a browser form submits `param_name1=param_value1&param_name2=param_value2` as a request body. If you have a field named `json` that contains JSON in your form, probably, you can get a JSON as follows:

```
post("/addRecord") {
  val jsonPayload = params("json")
  val x = parse(jsonPayload)
  ...
}
```

By the way, the json4s version that is used in Scalatra 2.7.0 is 3.6.7. It would be better to upgrade to this version: https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra/blob/v2.7.0/project/Dependencies.scala#L55